# Django Serializer page jump

Tags: django, redirect, django-rest-framework

I'm freshman in the Restful,I have some issues to figure out about 'Serializer page jump',the class is as follows, I want to know how to decide `name_instance` return to which page and how I can redirect other page with some object data?

```
class NameInteractiveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data['Name'] and validated_data['Name_SC']:
            pref_flag = "2"
            pref_name = validated_data['Name']
        elif validated_data['Name_SC']:
            pref_flag = "1"
            pref_name = validated_data['Name_SC']
        else:
            pref_flag = "2"
            pref_name = ""
        Name_instance = Name(
            Name=validated_data['Name'],
            Name_SC=validated_data['Name_SC'],
            Pref_Name_Flg=pref_flag,
            Status = '1',
        )
        name_instance.save()
        name=name_instance.save()
        return name
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by myself. Serializer is just to send data just like Json to fore-end,I can realize the function in the fore-end as follows,Angularjs is for example as follows:

```
var str_path = '/ui-contact/add/';
 $location.path(str_path).search({company_id: values.id});
  scope.$apply();
```

Yes! it's the answer what I want!